# Combining accent and character into one character in java 7

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, normalize

I am trying to write a java code that returns a single character combining both a character and an accent. The actual result of combining is a string and not one single character.
The following is a simple method to illustrate what I am trying to do. Thank you

```
private char convert (char c)
{
 if (c == '\u0130')
 {
  return '\u0069 \u0307'; // If the return value is String I get i. 
}                         //I need small i double dot
else return c;
}
```

Comment: if I understand correctly you want to return a string? why not private String convert(char c) and returning "\u0069" + "\u0307"?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Normalizer can decompose/compose your character as you like:

```
String decomposed = Normalizer.normalize(String.valueOf('ï'), Form.NFD);
```

result are two character (i, double-dot)

```
String composed = Normalizer.normalize(decomposed, Form.NFC);
```

result is one character (ï)

If I understand you correctly you seek

```
return Normalizer.normalize("\u0069\u0307", Form.NFC).charAt(0);
```

For double dots use `\u0308`.

Comment: Thank you so much, we lost 2-3 hours trying to find a solution to this <3