# Conversion of Japanese "semi-voice" character

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql, character-encoding, cjk, utf

I was trying to compare two spark dataframe which contains Japanese characters and there's some characters that seem the same but actually different to the program, such as プ vs プ

If you put them in utf-8 encoder:

プ utf-8 = \xE3\x83\x97

プ utf-8 = \xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x9A

Looks like フ(\xE3\x83\x95) + the little circle semi-voice sign(\xE3\x83\x95) = プ

What are these difference called, and is there any way to convert between them in Java/Scala?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`プ` aka `\xE3\x83\x97` *(UTF-8)* is `\u30d7` aka ['KATAKANA LETTER PU' (U+30D7)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30d7/index.htm).

`プ` aka `\xE3\x83\x95\xE3\x82\x9A` *(UTF-8)* is `\u30d5\u309a` aka ['KATAKANA LETTER HU' (U+30D5)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/30d5/index.htm) and ['COMBINING KATAKANA-HIRAGANA SEMI-VOICED SOUND MARK' (U+309A)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/309a/index.htm).

As you can see, the second is a base character and a combining character. This is the similar to how diacritical marks aka accent marks are done for Latin characters, e.g. how `ñ` = `n` + `̃`  aka [`\u00f1`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00f1/index.htm) = [`\u006e`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/006e/index.htm) + [`\u0303`](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0303/index.htm).

You can convert between the 2 forms using the `Normalizer` class. See: [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/Normalizer.html).

See also: [The Java™ Tutorials - Normalizing Text](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/normalizerapi.html).
See also: [Combining accent and character into one character in java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28873442/5221149)